# How I can call a function within its self?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I want to call quicksort function within its self in order to sort the array. I am facing error in QuickSort function in the code.

**Error:**

> NameError: name 'QuickSort' is not defined.

I am new in the pythons world. So, please help.

**Code:**

```py
from tkinter import *
import array as arr
import numpy as np
import random


class Program():
    def __init__(self,size,min_,max_):
        root = Tk()

        
        root.geometry("800x602")
        root.minsize(400,301)
        root.maxsize(800,602)

               
        self.Array_Size=IntVar(value=size)
        self.Minim_Elem=IntVar(value=min_)
        self.Maxim_Elem=IntVar(value=max_)

        La_1=Label(text="Size of Array" )
        La_1.place(x=150,y=50)
        E_1 = Entry(root,  textvariable=self.Array_Size)
        E_1.place(x=510,y=58, width=150,height=35) 


        La_2=Label(text="Minimum Elements")
        La_2.place(x=150,y=115)
        E_2= Entry(root,textvariable=self.Minim_Elem)
        E_2.place(x=510,y=122, width=150,height=35)


        La_3=Label(text="Maximum Elements")
        La_3.place(x=150,y=180)
        E_3 = Entry(root,self.Maxim_Elem)
        E_3.place(x=510,y=186, width=150,height=35)

        
        Gene_Array=Button(text="Generate Array",command=self.Genera_Array)
        Gene_Array.pack()
        Gene_Array.place(x=295,y=245, width=240,height=40)

        Quick=Button(text="Quick Sort",command=self.QuickSort)
        Quick.pack()
        Quick.place(x=410,y=410, width=120,height=40)



        self.Output_1=Text(root, width=56, height=3, bd=5, font=("Time new roman",12,"bold"))
        self.Output_1.place(x=150,y=300)

        
         root.mainloop()


    def Genera_Array(self):
    
        self.ArraySize=self.Array_Size.get()
        MinimumElement=self.Minim_Elem.get()
        MaximumElement=self.Maxim_Elem.get()
        self.Arr=[self.ArraySize]

        
        
        for H in range(0, self.ArraySize):
            self.Arr.append(random.randint(MinimumElement,MaximumElement))
        
        
        for A in range(0,self.ArraySize):
            self.Output_1.insert(END,self.Arr[A])
            self.Output_1.insert(END, " ")     
    
    
    
    
    
    def QuickSort(self):
    
        for A in range(0,self.ArraySize):
            print(self.Arr[A], end=" ")
        

        elements = len(self.Arr)
        
        if elements < 2:
            return self.Arr

        current_position = 0

        for H in range(1, elements):
            if self.Arr[H] <= self.Arr[0]:
                current_position += 1
                temp = self.Arr[H]
                self.Arr[H] = self.Arr[current_position]
                self.Arr[current_position] = temp

        
        temp = self.Arr[0]
        self.Arr[0] = self.Arr[current_position]
        self.Arr[current_position] = temp
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------          
       
        left = QuickSort(self.Arr[0:current_position])
        right = QuickSort(self.Arr[current_position+1:elements])
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.Arr = left + [self.Arr[current_position]] + right
        return self.Arr
p=Program(0,0,0)
```

Comment: `self.QuickSort`

Comment: As a side note, the widely respected conventions in Python are to only use capitalized names for class names. Respecting it helps others read your code.

Comment: You're using `class`, hence use `self.QuickSort`. The more pythonic way of swapping variables would be `a,b=b,a`, instead of the naïve approach.

Comment: In your call to QuickSort, you have arguments, but you don't have arguments in the function definition

Comment: Unless this is an excercise/assignment, you should use a library function for sorting.

Comment: Can anyone would please likely to help me through coding material from my above coding.As I'm not able to configure my solution  uptil now